# Traefik and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, docker, traefik

I have server with Docker and open 80 port.

I use Traefik to redirect between containers. And I want to host PostgreSQL database. After start conteiner with this settings:

```
  postgresql:
    image: orchardup/postgresql
    environment:
      - "POSTGRESQL_PASS=***"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Path:/postgresql/"
```

But is not work

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "is not work" is not really that clear. What's the error message?

Comment: @TheImpaler it just cant connection

Answer (score 5):

Traefik is a layer 7 reverse proxy.

Postgres doesn't use http, and requires a layer 4 proxy.

You need to look at using another product to proxy Postgres connections.

Answer (score 0):

I guess name of your host should be name of the postgres container, not name of the service. I suggest using container_name in your compose to be persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres does have a [http protocol](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/HTTP_API), but I think its way easier to just run it outside of Traefik. Keep your backend and frontend inside traefik, and the db outside:

```
docker pull postgres:latest
docker run -p 5432:5432 postgres
```